# Regex that makes IPV6 addresses shorter

Tags: regex, bash, shell, ipv6

For example, i have a dozen of IPV6 addresses, with 8 parts which are seperated by ":".
If the first few characters are null in these parts then i wanna remove them with a simple regex.

> **Input:**
>
> 1034:0123:0000:2100:3120:0000:0022:0001
>
> **Output:**
>
> 1034:123::2100:3120::22:1

Is it possible?

Comment: The regex itself can't make anything shorter, regex is just for pattern matching. What language are you using, so we know what functions to use for the actual replacement?

Comment: That IPv6 address is invalid; only one set of double colons can be present.

Comment: Thanks, i just thought it would be the easiest way.
Bash, ShellScript.

Comment: I suspect he means passing it through sed -e 's/regex/replace/g'

Comment: Doesn't matter, i just wanted to explain somehow what i wanna get.

Comment: I don't know enough about bash to provide an actual answer on replacing the 0s, but this regex `(^|:)0{1,4}` will identify and select everything that needs to be replaced.

Comment: Thanks!
It's almost perfect, but unfortunately it could detect only the first part with 0 start.
http://regex101.com/r/mA3lU3/1
Maybe a recursive method could solve this problem, or maybe do you know how could i set it to recursive?

Comment: Again, I'm not a bash expert, but in most languages you can add `/g` to the end to find all occurences so `/(^|:)0{1,4}/g` might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talked about it in the comments, but it works now so here's the answer.

```
/(^|:)0{1,4}/g
```

That regex should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's `socket` module to get

```
>>> socket.getaddrinfo('1034:0123:0000:2100:3120:0000:0022:0001', 0, socket.AF_INET6)
[(10, 1, 6, '', ('1034:123:0:2100:3120:0:22:1', 0, 0, 0)), (10, 2, 17, '', ('1034:123:0:2100:3120:0:22:1', 0, 0, 0)), (10, 3, 0, '', ('1034:123:0:2100:3120:0:22:1', 0, 0, 0))]

>>> socket.getaddrinfo('1034:0123:0000:2100:3120:0000:0022:0001', 0, socket.AF_INET6)[0][4][0]
'1034:123:0:2100:3120:0:22:1'
```

As you can see, the resulting IPv6 address has all the excess zeroes stripped out.

Comment: This is actually the correct notation according to https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5952#section-4.2.2. A single `:0:` should not be compressed to `::`